# Double-quotes are converted to < and >

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In my database there are data like this :

```
Axe 1. « Gouvernance, Etat de Droit, Sécurité, Décentralisation, Démocratie, Solidarité nationale ».
```

In my Hibernate sql I want to make a `where` condition :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pnd WHERE CONVERT(LOWER(TO_CHAR(PND_INTITULE)), 'US7ASCII') = :fk // fk will be replaced by the value `Axe 1. « Gouvernance, Etat de Droit, Sécurité, Décentralisation, Démocratie, Solidarité nationale ».`
```

The problem is that the count returns 0 ! I made a select statement getting `CONVERT(LOWER(TO_CHAR(PND_INTITULE))` then it returns data where the double-quotes are changed to be `<` for the opening quotes and `>` for the closing quotes ! So how to fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution occurs because of your `CONVERT`. I suppose the `US7ASCII` charset doesn't have the double-quote character so it uses whatever is closest.

```
SELECT LOWER(TO_CHAR('Axe 1. « Gouvernance ».')), -- axe 1. « gouvernance ».
       CONVERT(LOWER(TO_CHAR('Axe 1. « Gouvernance ».')),'US7ASCII') -- axe 1. < gouvernance >.
  FROM dual;
```

You have two options, either remove the `CONVERT` or add the same `CONVERT` on your bound variable `:fk`